How to pass the Keycloak token in React Native to achieve SSO automatic login in WebView?
I have a React Native app and it's logged by Keycloak(using react-native-app-auth), then I want to open a webview web page which also needs to be verified by Keycloak.
So, I want to login on web page directly using Keycloak SSO, how can I do it?
This is my React Native code, I can get access_token, refresh_token...

export const keycloak = {
  issuer: Config.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER as string,
  clientId: Config.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID as string,
  redirectUrl: OAUTH_REDIRECT_URL,
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access']
}

const tokens = await authorize(keycloak)

This is my Web page code, every time I open it from webview, I must login by hand.
export const keycloak = new Keycloak({
  realm: import.meta.env.VITE_KEY_CLOAK_REALM || '',
  url: import.meta.env.VITE_KEY_CLOAK_URL || '',
  clientId: import.meta.env.VITE_KEY_CLOAK_CLIENT_ID || ''
})

await keycloak.init({
  onLoad: 'login-required',
  checkLoginIframe: false
})

I don't know what params I should pass to webview and how web app Keycloak needs to use them.
